# Move files from Onedrive account to Office 365 account

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, cloud-storage

*Background*

1. I have a Onedrive account linked to my Microsoft account that I use
   to back-up my personal files.
2. I now have separately been granted an Office 365 account, which comes
   with unlimited storage.

*Issue*

As I am paying a fee (albeit small) to extend the size of the
   Onedrive capacity linked to my Microsoft account, I am keen to move
   some files between the two systems. The files I am looking to move
   exist only online.

A number of tools offer functionality to handle files between cloud accounts, ie

- [MultCloud](https://www.multcloud.com/#home)
- Rainbow drive (Microsoft Store)

Howvever both these options do not recognise attempts to connect to the Office 365 Account (they work with Microsoft Accounts only).

*Question*

Is there a way to move the files without a two-stage download (to pc), then upload (to Office 365)?

Comment: Mount both accounts has network shares.

Comment: @Ramhound thx - have managed to do that for the Microsoft account, still trying to accomplish that with the Office 365 account. Looks promising, thanks.